# Linux C: error of redefinition of in include headers

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I have a project, which has below header include map:

```
main.c <- main.h <- tcphelper.h <- tcptest.h <- util.h
                 <- udptest.h    <------------- util.h
```

In **util.h**, I defined a function prototype of **struct cpu_usage**:

```
void get_cpu_usage(struct cpu_usage *cu);
```

Now when I compile this project by GCC, I have this redefinition error. How do solve this problem?

thanks!

```
In file included from udptest.h:15:0,
                 from main.h:10,
                 from main.c:7:
util.h:27:8: error: redefinition of struct cpu_usage
 struct cpu_usage{
        ^
In file included from tcptest.h:14:0,
                 from tcphelper.h:10,
                 from main.h:9,
                 from main.c:7:
util.h:27:8: note: originally defined here
 struct cpu_usage{
        ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add [Include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to your header files to prevent including their contents multiple times. Example:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_INCLUDED
#define UTIL_H_INCLUDED

/* header contents goes here */

#endif /* UTIL_H_INCLUDED */
```

Comment: C 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use." implies to me that `_UTIL_H_` is reserved by the language.  Maybe `UTIL_H`

Comment: You are right, there may be a conflict with standard header. Another option is to add suffix like "_INCLUDED".